# tesseract.lib (version 4 ) for windows 10 (x64)

Tags: c++, tesseract

1. I find just Tesseract.lib (version 4.0.0) for windows10(x86) but I dont't find it for windows10(x64) .
2. So how can I get it or download it  ? and how I integrate it with C++ project (Cmake Project)  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[tesseract-ocr project](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/releases) does not provide binary release - best way is to compile by yourself.

There are [several ways/help tools (cppan, sw, vcpkg)](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Compiling#windows). If you want to have whole process under control you can get inspiration at blog (Building tesseract and leptonica with CMake and Clang on Windows)[3](http://www.sk-spell.sk.cx/building-tesseract-and-leptonica-with-cmake-and-clang-on-windows) - (clang can be easily replaced with msvc or mingw - in tesseract issue tracker there are described [experiences with android cross building](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/2337).